# Inconsistent results with get_time

Tags: c++, c++11, time-t

The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string time_str = "2017-01-03 09:30:00";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::istringstream ss(time_str);
        std::tm tm;
        ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        time_t t = std::mktime(&tm);
        std::cout << (int)t << " " << tm.tm_hour << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This program has inconsistent behavior. On my local machine with MinGW 8.1.0, it prints

```
1483453800 8
1483457400 9
1483457400 9
1483457400 9
1483457400 9
```

On Ideone, on both their Clang and GCC compilers, it prints

```
-1 9
-1 9
-1 9
-1 9
-1 9
```

What's up with this behavior? The Ideone output, which returns "-1" for time_t, suggests that I am messing up somewhere. The MinGW output, however, is even stranger because the first iteration of the loop has a different result from all the other iterations. My compiler and flags are in the comments.

Some other odd behavior is that if I change time_str to "1970-01-01 00:00:00", I get

```
18000 23
21600 0
21600 0
21600 0
21600 0
```

which is really weird both due to inconsistency and because epoch is stored as either 18000 or 21600 seconds instead of 0.

Comment: I can't reproduce [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xfnfbz). Can you share the exact compiler settings, and flags that you are using? Or simply link to the online compiler you're using?

Comment: The compiler is [MinGW x86_64 8.1.0 posix seh](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/seh/). I use commands
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -fexceptions -std=gnu++17  -c D:\Code\cbprojects\test\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o", followed by
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\test.exe obj\Release\main.o"

Comment: `std::tm tm;` needs complete initialization.  `get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` only filling some members, but not all as use by `mktime`.

Comment: Ah, that was the issue. It works now. I was assuming get_time filled in all members, but I guess not.